# Node.js & JQuery: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error. How do I use jquery with node on the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Help! I'm trying to use jquery in my node.js app, but I keep getting an error when I try to use '$', saying "$ is not defined"... but I defined it at the top! Here's what I did:

I installed both packages from npm like so:

```
npm install jquery
npm install jsdom
```

then I required them in my node.js app:

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
doSomething();
```

Then I'm trying to use it like so:

```
function doSomething(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
               ^
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Do you think that the `function` is getting executed *before* the `var $ =` part?

Thanks!

Versions:

- Node: 4.2.6
- Express: 4.12.4
- JQuery: 2.2.3
- JSDom: 8.3.0

## Update: Solution

Here's what I ended up using, based on everyone's answers!

```
var $;
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    $ = require("jquery")(window);
    doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your doSomething function is declared outside if the bounds of the jsdom.env function. $ is only accessible inside that callback. Something like this should work:

```
var $;

require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    $ = require("jquery")(window);
    doSomething();
});

 function doSomething(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
}
```

Though I think it would be more idiomatic to just declare doSomething inside the callback. That way it would have access to jquery from the outer scope.

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    function doSomething(){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
     }
    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
    doSomething();
});
```

Comment: bummer I thought I could get away with putting it up top and forgetting about it! This works great, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//make sure $ is available in the global scope
var $;

function doSomething(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
}

require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    // assign it
    $ = require("jquery")(window);

    // you have to call it in here because you are in a callback 
    doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a full DOM available and just want to parse and scrape/manipulate html elements, there is [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) which is more lightweight than `jsdom` and still gives you a jQuery-like API.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to move the call `doSomething()` inside your callback function right after `$` initialization.

```
// define global variable for further usage
var $;

require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    // initialize global variable
    $ = require("jquery")(window);

    // will work properly here
    doSomething();
});

function doSomething() {
    // using already initialized global variable
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
}
```

In your example there are 2 things you need to take care:

**1. Asynchronous functions**

We need to guarantee `doSomething` will be called only after `$` initialization.

**2. Variable scopes**

It really makes sense what is the place you declared `doSomething` function and in your example `doSomething` doesn't know `$` exists at all.  So we need to define it somewhere (e.g. globally) to make a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) with `$` variable.

Answer (score 0):

For current jsdom (**jsdom@24.0.0**) it seems that the correct way to use jquery is:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;

var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
```